# Parent component does not update if child component modifies Svelte store

Tags: svelte

I am new to Svelte. I am creating a `writeable` store like this:

```js
export const db = writable(collections);
```

example `collections` is shown below for clarity:

```js
export const collections = {
    "shakespeare": {
        "documents": {
            "merchant-of-venice": {
                "text": "",
                "size": 117826,
            },
            "julius-caesar": {
                "text": "",
                "size": 224,
            },
            "twelfth-night": {
                "text": "",
                "size": 533,
            },
        },
        "size": 416,
    },
    // more like this...
```

I am writing a component which will allow user to upload a file to the `writable` store. To do this I have a parent component `A` and a child component `B` that actually does the heavy work.

Parent component `A`:

```html
<script>
  import { db } from '$lib/memstore.js'
  export let documents = $db[collection].documents;
</script>
...
{#each Object.entries(documents) as [name, document]}
  // render in UI
{/each}
...
<B>Upload Button</B>
```

Child Component `B`:

```js
import { db } from './memstore';
let documentStore = $db[collection].documents;

async function uploadFiles() {
    ...
    documentStore[id] = {
        text: text,
        size: text.length
    }
}
```

I can run the code and there is no error. The problem is that the parent component does not update. There is no re-render pass when a file is uploaded and `documentStore` is modified by the child component `B`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in that doing `let documents = $db[collection].documents` kind of disconnects the documents variable from the store, from now on Svelte will think you are working purely on a local variable.

Instead you should modify the *store* itself when adding or removing items and use reactivity to update any properties you extract from it.

for example:

```js
$: documents = $db["shakespeare"].documents

function add() {
  $db["shakespeare"].documents["the-taming-of-the-shrew"] = {}
}
```

with this code the variable `documents` will be kept in sync at all times with the value in the store, in the `add` function I modify the store directly, thanks to the reactivity this means that  `documents` will be updated as well.

this is of course a very crude example but it shows the basic principle, you can easily adapt and develop this further if you dig a bit more in how stores and reactivity work in Svelte.